# Use Mapbox in Unity app without hanging Unity & editor at startup

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-unity

I have a Unity app that's more or less an agglomeration of the Mapbox "ZoomableMap" example from the Mapbox Unity SDK .unitypackage and my own code (C#, attached to an empty GameObject).

When I hit 'play' in the Unity Editor, my code takes about 2 seconds to initialize when Mapbox is disabled (by disabling everything related to Mapbox by un-checking them in the 'Inspector' pane).

If I enable the Mapbox objects (with or without enabling my own), the Unity editor hangs for about 30-70 seconds before the map appears & everything runs normally (usually, around 15-80fps). About 5-10% of the time, it'll go into a death spiral while initializing, zoom past 95% memory utilization (I have 16gb), and just thrash (Unity Editor UI still completely unresponsive) until one of two things happens: Unity Editor crashes with an error saying that the video card is out of memory (and an unhelpful link to a page at nvidia that says basically nothing except, "If you run out of memory, your program will crash."), or I'll get tired of waiting for the inevitable crash & kill Unity with Windows Task Manager after 2-3 minutes.

Is there any way to make Mapbox initialization a bit more graceful and threaded/background-friendly so that MY code can run & execute right away while Mapbox politely does its initialization and subsequent updates in the background (without freezing either Unity Editor's UI or my own program's execution)?

```
Details: 
    Unity 2018.1.6f1-MLTP7 (from the MagicLeap SDK)
    mapbox-unity-sdk_v1.4.5.unitypackage
```

Note: I can post additional details, I'm just not entirely sure how to describe something that consists of mostly boilerplate library items with hundreds of settings in the Inspector pane... does Unity have a "dump a plaintext (or Markdown-friendly) representation of an object's entire Inspector hierarchy and its current values for convenient posting to StackOverflow" function hidden somewhere?

Note 2: It's apparently a known issue with Mapbox-Unity (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/262). Attempting to track down a newer version that incorporates changes to improve its threading (someone submitted a patch almost exactly a year ago to address it, but the patch appears to have gone away in the meantime).

Note 3: The map is admittedly huge... basically, the entirety of northern Florida, Georgia, Alabama, and South Carolina, viewed from a north-facing vantage point ~50km above the Gulf of Mexico at a 45-degree angle. It's admittedly not a common use case (even for my own program), but it's a use case that's far from inconceivable & my program has to be at least somewhat capable of handling gracefully.

Comment: It's a real nuisance, and a good question.  Is it connecting to the net to get some stuff, that's a common nuisance w/ that type of startup issue in Unity.

Comment: Hmmm... while hunting around a bit more, I found this in the error tracker for Mapbox-Unity at Github ( https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/262 ) which appears to describe the problem almost perfectly. It looks like one of the developers ("brnkhy") submitted a fix to address the problem almost exactly one year ago, but the link he posted to the branch is now dead. Still attempting to figure out why...